# jquery bxSlider slides shifted to right on first pass

Tags: jquery, bxslider

My slides are shifted to right on the first loop. It's like there is a 50px padding-right.
On the second pass, they are ok. Can someone find why ?

See at:

http://www.cadoh.net/dev/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the issue. Its because of the below css.

```
ul#sponsors li {
    display: inline-block; // This is the line which causing the problem
    list-style: none; 
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Change `display: inline-block;` to `display: list-item;` or something similar ( or you can even remove it.)